# Bar and point plot with repeat data

Tags: r, ggplot2, pivot

So I have data of the form:

data =

| group | condition | value | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Health | 1.0000000 | Simulated |
| B | Health | 1.0000000 | Simulated |
| C | Health | 1.0000000 | Simulated |
| A | Disease | 0.4589925 | Simulated |
| B | Disease | 1.4905422 | Simulated |
| C | Disease | 1.3422035 | Simulated |
| A | Health | 1.0000000 | Experimental |
| B | Health | 1.0000000 | Experimental |
| C | Health | 1.0000000 | Experimental |
| A | Disease | 0.5158371 | Experimental |
| A | Disease | 0.7559055 | Experimental |
| B | Disease | 1.4153005 | Experimental |
| B | Disease | 1.4000000 | Experimental |
| C | Disease | 1.3300971 | Experimental |
| C | Disease | 1.0000000 | Experimental |

I wish to make a stacked plot.  Along the X axis is Group (3) and along the Y axis is the value.  Each group should have two bars (one for health, and one for disease).  On top of this, I am trying to overlay a point plot with my experimental values.

I have managed to do this when there is only one Experimental value for each condition using:

`pivoted<-data %>% pivot_wider(names_from =Source)`.

`ggplot(pivoted, aes(x=group,fill=condition)) + geom_col(aes(y=Simulated), position=position_dodge()) + labs(x="Group", y="Value") + geom_point(aes(y=Experimental), position = position_dodge(width=0.9), size=3)`

However, now there are repeats this method is not working.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: please enter your data in a reproducible way: you can use dput() function to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would suggest subsetting your data rather than pivoting:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = condition)) +
  geom_col(data = filter(data, Source == "Simulated"),
           position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_point(
    data = filter(data, Source == "Experimental"),
    aes(group = condition),
    position = position_dodge(width = 1)
  )
```

[image]

---

Using this data

```
data = read.table(text = 'group     condition   value   Source
A   Health  1.0000000   Simulated
B   Health  1.0000000   Simulated
C   Health  1.0000000   Simulated
A   Disease     0.4589925   Simulated
B   Disease     1.4905422   Simulated
C   Disease     1.3422035   Simulated
A   Health  1.0000000   Experimental
B   Health  1.0000000   Experimental
C   Health  1.0000000   Experimental
A   Disease     0.5158371   Experimental
A   Disease     0.7559055   Experimental
B   Disease     1.4153005   Experimental
B   Disease     1.4000000   Experimental
C   Disease     1.3300971   Experimental
C   Disease     1.0000000   Experimental', header = T)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much!  Worked a treat